# Force merge branches

Tags: mercurial

Is there any way to force merge branch A in branch B where all possible conflicts will be resolved in favor of branch B?

In any words how to push last branch B revision in branch A without vanity around conflicts?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can decide to take all of one branch over another by using `hg merge --tool internal:other` or `hg merge --tool internal:local`

I'm not sure which way you want to merge but if you want to merge A into B taking all changes from B then you would do the following:

```
> hg update B
> hg merge A --tool internal:local
> hg commit -m "Merge"
```

The `internal:local` merge tool will take the changes in the current revision (which is B because of the `hg update B`) over the changes in the other revision, `internal:other` would take all changes from A.

For more info use the following commands:  `hg help merge` and `hg help merge-tools`

Comment: Is hg help merge-tools, at least in 2.0.